# Visual Studio 2019 is configured for:c++17 but it looks more like c++14

Tags: c++17, visual-studio-2019

[image: VS2019 Project properties showing c++17]

If I compile some code with the following:

```
#include <string_view>

std::string_view strv{ "Test 1" };
```

I get this error:

```
Error C2065 'string_view': undeclared identifier...
```

I tried some other c++17 code and not of it works.
I get the same errors if the C++ Language Standard is set to std:c++14

The Properties-->C/C++-->Command line contains  /std:c++17
but the actual compiler command line that runs does not have this option set.

This is a community version of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.1

Comment: `Properties-->C/C++-->Command line` Make sure you look at the same configuration that you are compiling.

Comment: That's a good comment, but yes I checked that I was compiling with the right configuration. I also just compiled the c++ file (not the whole project), the c++ file's Properties-->C/C++-->Command line has the /std:c++17 option.

Comment: That's an odd one, then. I can only suggest you turn build verbosity up and try to follow what's going on in the logfiles.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a few more tries. Then I will just reinstall VS2019. If it works I will report back.

Comment: It would be interesting if you could post the entire `.vcxproj` file here, or at least the `<ClCompile>` sections of it.

Comment: Actually I did not try editing the .vcproj file, but I will post the <ItemConfigurationGroup>

Answer (score 0):

user dxiv pointed out the problem is in the Property pages Platform pulldown it should be set to ALL Platforms (or set C++17 individually for Win32 and x64 platforms).

[image]

Comment: The .vcxproj only shows the `<LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>` line under the `x64` configurations. Make sure Platforms is set to All Platforms in the property page where you select C++17.

Comment: And "All Configurations" as well.